# Bitbake recipe for a qml application using meta-qt6

Tags: qt, cmake, qml, yocto

I've got a very simple QML application that I'm trying to build with Yocto (Kirkstone) & the meta-qt6 (open source) layer. I'm currently having issues with CMake & I'm fairly sure its because my CmakeLists.txt is incorrect, i.e. the target is not getting built.

If anyone has successfully compiled with meta-qt6 in a recipe I'd appreciate any pointers!

My recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "QT QML Test Recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://CMakeLists.txt        \
           file://CMakeLists.txt.user   \
           file://main.cpp              \
           file://Main.qml              \
          "

DEPENDS += " packagegroup-qt6-modules "

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

# Not needed as install is handled by cmake..
# do_install:append() {
#    install -d ${D}${bindir}
#    install -m 0755${WORKDIR}/build/qt-qml-demo ${D}${bindir}
#}

inherit qt6-cmake
```

Project layout:

```
├── files
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt.user
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── Main.qml
└── qt-qml-demo_0.1.bb
```

My CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(qt-qml-demo VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(CMakePrintHelpers)

set(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR 6)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR 2)
set(PROJECT_VERSION 6.2.4)

cmake_print_variables(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)
cmake_print_variables(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR)
# Should output WORKDIR
cmake_print_variables(${S})

install(TARGETS qt-qml-demo
  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${S}"
  BUNDLE DESTINATION "${S}"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${S}"
)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
```

My output:

```
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /media/user/yocto/dir/meta-raspberrypi/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qt-qml-demo/0.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ - skipped

-- Detecting CXX compile features

-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

-- PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR="/media/user/yocto/dir/meta-raspberrypi/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qt-qml-demo/0.1-r0"

-- PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR="6"

$(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR)


$(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (install):
  install TARGETS given target "qt-qml-demo" which does not exist.




-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/media/user/yocto/dir/meta-raspberrypi/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/qt-qml-demo/0.1-r0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

+ bb_sh_exit_handler
+ ret=1
+ [ 1 != 0 ]
+ echo WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
+ exit 1
```

Comment: Side note: The `CMakeLists.txt.user` file is not needed to build it. That's just something QtCreator generates to hold your project settings.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, the CMake target "qt-qml-demo" does not exists. Usually in a CMakeLists, you either build library via add_library() or binaries via add_executable(). You are missing one of those lines

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a working solution. Thanks for the comments. The project layout is now:

```
├── files
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── Main.qml
└── qt-qml-demo_0.1.bb
```

My CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(qml_demo VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(CMakePrintHelpers)

set(PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR 6)
set(PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR 2)
set(PROJECT_VERSION 6.2.4)

# Seems to be important that 'find_package' comes before other calls below
find_package(Qt6
    CONFIG
    REQUIRED
    COMPONENTS
        BuildInternals
        Quick
        Core
        Qml
        Gui
)

qt_add_executable(app_qml_demo
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(app_qml_demo
    URI qml_demo
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)

# Some of this below may not be required, to investigate
set_target_properties(app_qml_demo PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(app_qml_demo
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

install(TARGETS app_qml_demo
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

& qt-qml-demo_0.1.bb

```
SUMMARY = "QT QML Test Recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://CMakeLists.txt         \
           file://main.cpp              \
           file://Main.qml              "

DEPENDS += " qtbase \
             qtdeclarative-native \
             qtquick3d"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit qt6-cmake
```

This creates a binary that is successfully populated to the image. The only outstanding issue is that main.cpp uses an inappropriate file path method:

```
QUrl url(u"qrc:/qt-qml-demo/Main.qml"_qs);
```

which doesn't work on the embedded target (a RPi4). It should be a straightforward fix, anyone interested should find an updated recipe [here](https://github.com/OOHehir/meta-test/tree/main/recipes-qt/recipes-qt/qml-demo) at some point in the future.

I'm sure this answer could be improved, I'd be glad of any input but at least this might be a starting point for others.